# Как сохранить переменную на processing?

Tags: строки, txt, processing

У меня есть переменная типа String и я хочу её сохранить в файл с расширением .txt. В интернете не много материалов на эту тему! Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Можно [так](https://processing.org/reference/createWriter_.html) можно [так](https://processing.org/reference/saveStrings_.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String data = "Текст для сохранения"; // Ваша переменная типа String

void setup() {
  String filePath = "C:/путь/к/файлу/output.txt";
  saveStrings(filePath, new String[] {data});
}
```

В файл "C:/путь/к/файлу/output.txt" (`filePath`) будет сохранена переменная `data` (ваша переменная). Она будет преобразована в `String[]`, поскольку функция `saveStrings` сохраняет его.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять более развёрнутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit].

Comment: Исправил данный ответ